# Flashpunk collision troubles

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make my character collide with a pot, but I keep running into problems.

My code is currently (this is inside the update function):

```
        if (collide("Pot",MyWorld.Pot.graphic.x,MyWorld.Pot.graphic.y))
        {
            trace("HUH!?")
            // Player is colliding with a "bullet" type.
        }
```

It never traces "HUH?!" even though I go to the pot. I've even tried creating my character at 80, 80 (which is the position of the pot)

If I type 0,0 it works, so why not 80,80?

The hitbox for the pot is 36x34 (it's frame size for it's spritemap)

Here's the code for the pot (inside a separate class)

public class Po extends Entity
{

```
[Embed(source = "../img/28x29.png")]

public var PotImage:Class;

public var sprPot:Spritemap = new Spritemap(PotImage,36,34)

public function Po(xP:Number,yP:Number)
{
    sprPot.add("Break",[0,1],2,false)
    graphic = sprPot
    graphic.x = xP
    sprPot.unlock()
    setHitbox(36,34)
    type = "Pot"
    graphic.y = yP
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to change the position of the entity just use its `x` and `y` properties. The x,y in graphic are just offsets.

Secondly, to check for collision just do

```
if (collide("pot", x, y)) trace("killed by pot!");
```

The second and third arguments are coordinates `this` entity is placed in order to check for collision. The most common case is you check new position of entity and see if it collides with some obstacles if not you place it there.